# Como desabilitar miniatura dentro do post no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, thumbnail

Ola, gostaria de saber como desabilito a miniatura dentro do post no wordpress, que ela só apareça na home apos fazer o post mas dentro do post ela fique desativada e não apareça

Answer (score 0):

Eu tentaria adicionar o código abaixo no seu functions.php:

```
function remover_post_thumbnail($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr){
if(is_single($post_id)){
    return '';
}
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', remover_post_thumbnail );
```